# Restart previous fragment from current Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I have a fragment called A. A starts new Activity B.
What I want to achieve is when B finish, it will return to fragment A and restart/ rerun it.
` override fun finish() {

```
    val fragment = com.example.x_comic.views.main.fragments.Collection();
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.collection_frag, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    super.finish()
}`
```

I have seen many recommendation using this solution. But I dont know how to get the id of fragment A to replace with new fragment

Im getting this error
No view found for id 0x7f0a0561 (com.example.x_comic:id/collection_frag) for fragment Collection{19a8efd}

Please help. Many thanks!`

Comment: Post your .xml file containing the fragment. And what is fragments.Collection()?